# Expedient phosponium synthesis (for Wittig)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, kinetics, solvents

I have been making ethyltriphenylphosphonium bromide (somewhat of a time crunch, would have used iodoethane instead of bromoethane if we didn't have to wait for it). All the syntheses I see of Wittig salts are in aromatic solvents and they take large amounts of time for what I would have expected to be a fairly quick reaction, usually at least a day, if not several. I have come across the use of iodide salts as a catalyst, some of which I had already added because I figured it wouldn't hurt.

$$\ce{PPh3 + EtBr ->[\text{aromatic}][\text{solvent}] [EtPPh3]Br}$$

Why are these conditions standard/most effective? More specifically, **why is toluene (less often xylene, probably others but those are the two I've seen) used rather than some polar aprotic solvent?** Also, besides increased temperature and the use of iodide catalysts, **are there any common ways to decrease reaction time?**

- Is it simply that toluene boils at a relatively high temperature? Maybe the S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction is fairly easy once line up, but due to the large PPh<sub>3</sub> being a bulky nucleophile, having the two reactive sites in close proximity is relatively rare, so increasing temperature is the most effect thing since random interaction is the driving force.
- I can't imagine a primary alkylbromide reacts through S<sub>N</sub>1 rather than S<sub>N</sub>2. I guess maybe the higher temperature could allow for an S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction, though? I kinda doubt it, though...
- I would think, even if the above was true, using THF and going through an S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism at a lower temperature would be simpler than refluxing in toluene, and I still kind of doubt the S<sub>N</sub>1 on a primary bromide even at the elevated temperature.
- Another thought is that the phosphonium salt crashes out of toluene, and therefore this equilibrium serves as a driving force for the reaction. Technically, this doesn't speed up the reaction, but it does significantly hinder the reverse reaction, so it leads to a net decrease in reaction time (and increases yield, I guess, if the reverse reaction is significant). I wouldn't really think the halide anions would be strong enough nucleophiles to be able to kick off a phosphine, though.

$$\ce{RX + PPh3}\xrightarrow{\text{toluene}}\ce{\underset{\small{(\sim none\ in\ sol'n)}}{[RPPh3]X_{$(s)$}} v}$$
$$\text{vs.}$$
$$\ce{RX + PPh3} \stackrel{\small{\text{THF}}}{\longrightleftharpoons} 
\ce{\underset{\small{(more\ than\ above)}}{[RPPh3]X_{$(org)$}}}$$

I realize THF isn't all that polar, but relative to toluene or xylene, I would really expect it to facilitate this reaction better.

---

P.S. This question isn't really an attempt to get help with my current situation (especially since I just finished working up my last batch, anyway) as much as it is just trying to get general information about the reaction.

I will mention for anyone who might be able to use it that I first tried to run mine in toluene at around 35 °C with catalytic KI (I've now seen LiI used instead of KI, not sure how much that matters). However, I was inspired by a literature report of a 7-day reaction at 30 °C (no iodide) to move the reaction in portions to pressure tubes and take it up to 130 °C. A paper reported 7 h (also no iodide) at this temp was effective, and I found that to be overkill. I didn't really see much difference between 2 h and 7 h (again, no iodide in their reaction, which may have caused the difference).

Comment: Depending on the substrate, and the wanted $E/Z$-configuration of the alkene formed, an Arbuzov reaction (like 1.1 eq of triethylphosphite per 1 eq of alkylhalogenide; the former often deployed both reagent and solvent), refluxed for 1-3 h; telescoped / followed by a HWE with NaOEt could have been faster, easier to workup.

Comment: @Buttonwood I'm having a hard time parsing your description there, but it sounds like it's definitely worth exploring. Ill have to draw it out, I think... I get everything up to how the NaOEt part works. Wouldn't I end up with the $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated ethyl ester back from that? I also considered using diethyl ethylphosphonate as the ethylenation reagent.

Comment: I was extrapolating from work done earlier, see in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55185/comment-on-expedient-phosponium-synthesis-for-wittig